# Public data sets in JSON format

Tags: json, dataset, bigdata, public

Where can I find public dataset in Json format? I am looking for one in 10-20GB range. Currently the big datasets I am getting are in XML format

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

http://www.json-generator.com/

You can create random JSON data with the specific size you need.